# Building merge requests in CI server

Tags: git, teamcity, gitlab

We are using GitLab to manage our repos. We are trying to follow GitFlow processes and as part of that we would like to be able to build and execute the tests against any merge request automatically in TeamCity.

From what I can see this is possible in GitLab CI but moving over to that isn't a realistic option for us.

I have seen tutorials about achieving this on GitHUB using a branch specification like +refs/pull/*/merge - does a similar branch specification get created by GitLAB?

We are using version 4.2 of GitLab but can upgrade if required for this feature and version 8 of TeamCity

Comment: I think this would be really useful. A merge request builder is available for Jenkins, but I cannot find an equivalent for TeamCity (https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-merge-request-builder-plugin). Looking through the source of this plugin though suggested that it is much more complicated than just watching something like +refs/pull/*/merge.

Answer (score 11):

I have GitLab 6.3 and TeamCity 8 and I need build feature branches too. We have following workflow (it is based on git-flow, but slightly changed according to our release cycle).

So, we have `development` branch and one pushes feature branch with a specific name `dev/feature-name-here`.

Next, one creating a Merge Request in GitLab from `dev/feature-name-here` to `development`.

TeamCity is configured to automatically run builds for each branch with the following refspec: `+:refs/heads/dev/(*)` so we can see a build for branch `feature-name-here` is automatically started.

Next, I have a custom script which is embedded to GitLab's merge request page. It do the following.

1. Detects a source and target branch by looking at a MR page
2. With TeamCity REST API enumerates build which is belongs to a target branch (in TeamCity 8 we can assign custom build configuration ID to build so we using some semantic naming like `devUnit`, `devIntegration`, `devWhatever`, etc...)
3. Creates a table witch contains build status images for source and target branches for each related build configuration.

Now it looks like this:

[image: TC Build status at GitLab]

Now this approach has some drawbacks like if one updates a branch with another push I can't figure out from GitLab page is new commits is already built or I'm seeng old build status, so I need to click on a build link and check in TeamCity

Comment: I have this set up to build the merge requests to master. We create hot fixes with name 'hf/<feature>'. Teamcity is picking up the branches but its not autobuilding. Is there any specific setting in the build trigger?

Comment: We do nothing special except standard vcs build triggers. They are configured without any filters and exceptions - just start if changes is detected.

Comment: Hi @Olegas, where can i get more information on how do you achieve this?

Comment: Hi @CarlosCastellanos! Drop me a line (see my SO profile for email address) and I'll answer you questions there.

Comment: Hi @Olegas, sent you an email, can you please advice me ASAP??, my main problem is integrating build results into merge request page, you can focus on that if you are short of time

Comment: @Olegas I am also interested in how you accomplished the back reporting of test results to the gitlab pull request page. Unfortunately I can't see your email address in your SO profile?

Comment: @fkrauthan - oleg-elifantiev@yandex.ru

Comment: Thanks, and it would be great to have some tutorial article how to achieve this. Although I'd prefer different strategy - run builds only when merge request happens and then locally merge the feature branch with master and then report the status. I guess, this could be done with GitLab webhooks - they should call some outer URL script which then somehow activates TeamCity build agent with source branch name as argument through TeamCity REST API: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/REST+API#RESTAPI-triggerBuild